# Java Bounded Generics: Type inference bug? (Method invocation, JLS 15.12.2.7)

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, type-inference, jls

For the following snippet of code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    interface Interface1<T> {}
    interface Interface2<T> extends Interface1<T> {}
    static class Bound {}
    interface BoundedI1<T extends Bound> extends Interface1<T> {}
    interface BoundedI2<T extends Bound> extends Interface2<T> {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test((List<BoundedI2<?>>) null);
        //test2((List<BoundedI2<?>>) null);
    }

    public static void test(List<? extends Interface2<? extends Bound>> list) { test2(list); }

    public static void test2(List<? extends Interface1<? extends Bound>> list) {}
}
```

The compiler is OK with the first call, but complains if I uncomment the second.  Is this a bug in the type inference system, or can someone explain why the inference rules in the JLS fail here?

Tested on both 6u43 and 7u45 Oracle JDKs.

UPDATE: Seems like eclipsec accepts it just fine.  Unfortunately I can't really change up our toolchain :P, but it is interesting to find differences in the compilers.

The error message, as printed by ideone (cool tool btw):

```
Main.java:12: error: method test2 in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
        test2((List<BoundedI2<?>>) null);
        ^
  required: List<? extends Interface1<? extends Bound>>
  found: List<BoundedI2<?>>
  reason: actual argument List<BoundedI2<?>> cannot be converted to List<? extends Interface1<? extends Bound>> by method invocation conversion
```

UPDATE 2: This compiles fine, which indicates that the compiler does think `BoundedI2<?>` is assignable to `Interface1<? extends Bound>`, which seems to more directly contradict the JLS:

```
public class Main {
    interface Interface1<T> {}
    interface Interface2<T> extends Interface1<T> {}
    static class Bound {}
    interface BoundedI1<T extends Bound> extends Interface1<T> {}
    interface BoundedI2<T extends Bound> extends Interface2<T> {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test((List<BoundedI2<?>>) null);
        //test2((List<BoundedI2<?>>) null);
        test3((BoundedI2<?>) null);
    }

    public static void test(List<? extends Interface2<? extends Bound>> list) { test2(list); }

    public static void test2(List<? extends Interface1<? extends Bound>> list) {}
    public static void test3(Interface1<? extends Bound> instance) {}
}
```

Comment: I stuck your code in eclipse using java 1.6.0_26-b03 and it compiled without complaint.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @azurefrog: You did uncomment the commented line, right? [When I try](http://ideone.com/1w2Yzq), I get the error.

Comment: Yes, I left both lines uncommented. I went into my preferences and turned on every option for errors on generics and still eclipse is quite happy compiling your code.

Comment: While eclipse is perfectly happy with that code, when I try to compile it using `javac` from the command line, I do get an error: `test2 (java.util.List<? extends Main.Interface1<? extends Main.Bound>>) in Main cannot be applied to (java.util.List<Main.BoundedI2<?>>)`.  I've double checked the path that eclipse is using to make sure it's the same compiler.  This is very interesting.

Comment: It is ok here. Tested with eclipse + jdk1.7.0_45

Comment: This also doesn't compile with JDK 1.8.0_05, so the improved type inference rules in Java 8 didn't fix this.... Interestingly, replacing `<?>` with `<? extends Bound>` in the commented-out line results in no error. It *could* be possible that the inference rules don't account for this kind of "combining" of multiple inference types, but I'm not familiar enough with the rules to say whether that is the case. There's another issue in that I'm not sure if the `<?>` should be properly taken as `<? extends Object>` or `<? extends Bound>`, but that's another issue...

Comment: I'm getting confused here. Shouldn't `test()` be not compiling, since `List<BoundedI2<?>>` isn't assignable to `List<? extends Interface2<? extends Bound>>`? Specifically, `BoundedI2` extends `Interface2`, but `<?>` isn't `<? extends Bound>`. Am I missing something? If `BoundedI2` is defined to take `<T extends Bound>`, is the compiler smart enough to know that `<?>` should be `<? extends Bound>`? Is that even a valid claim to make?

Comment: OK, I *think* I might have figured out at least part of the problem. I think the difference between the compilers comes down to figuring out when an unbounded wildcard is really truly unbounded, i.e. when `<?>` really means `<? extends Bound>`, in this case. Evidently Eclipse is better at figuring that out, based on the lack of an error message. Unfortunately, I cannot find any JLS passages at the moment describing this behavior, so I can't tell you for sure if this is a bug or simply Eclipse going above and beyond.

Comment: The strange thing is that the compiler figures it out once (as evidenced by the `test` call you pointed out) but seems to be unable to figure the same thing out one more step removed, which seems unusual since the algorithm described by the JLS seems to be fully recursive, with no real "maximum complexity limits" to speak of.  In particular, the compiler determines that `List<BoundedI2<?>>` is assignable to `List<? extends Interface2<? extends Bound>>`, ostensibly because `BoundedI2<?>` is assignable to `Interface2<? extends Bound>`; why not `Interface1<? extends Bound>` as well?

Comment: I think you're right. Both `Interface1<? extends Bound> i = (BoundedI2<?>) null;` and `Interface2<? extends Bound> i = (BoundedI2<?>) null;` compile without complaint, yet "wrapping" those in the type parameter for a `List` causes the compiler to give up. I'm leaning towards this being a bug in `javac`. You could try submitting a bug report to Oracle, although whether it'd be addressed, who knows (didn't get a response for the last report I submitted, so not too pleased with them). Also, you can send a notif to someone using @<username>. Not sure if you were responding to me, but just in case.

Comment: Also, as a side note the particular section you reference in JLS 8 doesn't exist. Doesn't really seem to matter too much, though, as the bug remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the command line compiler have some difficulties handling at the same time

- the fact that BoundedI2 is generic on T which must be a "Bound"
- the fact that Interface2 is extending Interface1

At least without instanciating BoundedI2 correctly. What is strange indeed is that Eclipse configured on the same JDK compiles it just fine... Note that Eclipse uses it's internal compiler in order to handle incremental recompulation while you type, so it does not invoke the JDK's compiler at all (see org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler package).

This modification makes it compile ok both in Eclipse and in the command line, by forcing BoundedI2 to be on a concrete type rather than on a type inference:

```
import java.util.List;

public class PerfTest {
    interface Interface1<T> {}
    interface Interface2<T> extends Interface1<T> {}
    static class Bound {}
    interface BoundedI1<T extends Bound> extends Interface1<T> {}
    interface BoundedI2<T extends Bound> extends Interface2<T> {}
    static class Actual extends Bound {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test((List<BoundedI2<Actual>>) null);
        test2((List<BoundedI2<Actual>>) null);
    }

    public static void test(List<? extends Interface2<? extends Bound>> list) { test2(list); }

    public static void test2(List<? extends Interface1<? extends Bound>> list) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently tracking bug report at OpenJDK, with some comments for insight: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051807